# Why is $\mathsf{Type} : \mathsf{Type}$ a contradiction?

Tags: logic

In reading [this cstheory.se question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/21836/why-does-coq-have-prop) and [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322534/coq-prop-versus-set-in-typen), they mention that $\mathsf{Type}: \mathsf{Type}$ is inconsistent. I also understand that Coq has an infinite hierarchy of Types.

But why is $\mathsf{Type}: \mathsf{Type}$ considered inconsistent in logic?

Comment: This is just Russel's paradox.

Comment: @user40276 No. This is Girard's paradox.

Comment: @ZhenLin This is just a matter of notation since the derivation is more or less the same one.

Comment: No, it is not a matter of notation. Girard's paradox is more like the Burali-Forti paradox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a complement to Zhen Lin's comment above, see Coq's [Frequently Asked Questions](https://coq.inria.fr/faq#htoc42) section 37:

> **37  Is $\text{Type}$ impredicative?**
>
> No, $\text{Type}$ is stratified. This is hidden for the user, but Coq internally maintains a set of constraints ensuring stratification.
>
> If $\text{Type}$ were impredicative then it would be possible to encode Girard's systems U− and U in Coq and it is known from Girard, Coquand, Hurkens and Miquel that systems U− and U are inconsistent [Girard 1972, Coquand 1991, Hurkens 1993, Miquel 2001]. This encoding can be found in file Logic/Hurkens.v of Coq standard library.
>
> For instance, when the user see ∀ X:Type, X->X : Type , each occurrence of Type is implicitly bound to a different level, say α and β and the actual statement is forall X:Type(α), X->X : Type(β) with the constraint α<β.
>
> When a statement violates a constraint, the message $\text{Universe inconsistency}$ appears. Example: fun (x : Type) (y : ∀ X : Type, X -> X) => y x x .

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error when trying to reproduce the last example. Is there a typo?